# Azure storage option for 10-100MB json files as a source for HDInsigt Hadoop/Spark

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake

There are 2 options to store json files for future processing by Hadoop or Spark in Azure cloud.

- Azure Data Lake Store
- Azure CosmosDB

Both option have good HDInsigt integration, BUT recommended file size for ADLS should be at least 100MB and maximum file size for document collection in ComsosDB is 2MB, so what should I do here if my files average 20MB?

Comment: `maximum file size for document collection in ComsosDB is 2MB`...I believe this restriction is for a document attachment which is different than a JSON document. You can have as many JSON documents as you want in a Cosmos DB collection.

Comment: Also, please don't forget about Azure Blob Storage. You can store your JSON files in Azure Blob Storage and process these files by Hadoop or Spark.

Comment: @GauravMantri https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#documents

"You can insert, replace, delete, read, enumerate, and query arbitrary JSON documents in a collection. Azure Cosmos DB does not mandate any schema and does not require secondary indexes in order to support querying over documents in a collection. The maximum size for a document is 2 MB."

Comment: "Also, please don't forget about Azure Blob Storage." Yes, it seems for me last option.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong but your JSON file contain many documents (probably in an array) and not a single document? The limit is 2MB per document.

Comment: Is your JSON file one big document or lots of JSON documents in one file? How many files do you have? Also if you are considering data lake store, are you considering data lake analytics / u-sql?

Comment: @Alex KeySmith not millions, maybe up to 1million documents 1-4mb size

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Data Lake Store, there is a document describing best practices, and one of those does recommend larger files for performance:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-best-practices